# Possible to allow users access to specific (already existing) google sheets documents?

Tags: web-applications, oauth, google-sheets

Trying to create a user-based website where people can gather information from their personal google sheet and edit and add information from within my site. Anyone with experience in this kind of thing willing to point me in the right direction? I know allowing access to specific documents can be troublesome because of the Oauth key, can anyone provide insight as to how that whole thing works?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Its not easy mainly because its an old API. To access other peoples data you will need to use Oauth2.   https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en